# "Microsoft NuGet - Package installation failed" error while installing Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I attempted to repair my existing install of Visual Studio 2013 today (I installed it last night and got an unknown error, followed by a ton of package errors on launch) and was greeted with this message: [image: error message]

Googling didn't reveal anything, so I thought I would ask here. [Here are the logfiles](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/202386712/vslogs.cab) I got with the log collector [as discussed here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2899270#furtherhelp).

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: @0ctoDragon - Yeah, I tried reinstalling a good half-dozen times, but the only solution that would work was just finishing the installation and then [manually downloading and installing NuGet](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca).

Answer (score 12):

This is also the result of running Update 4 (Nov 2014) after applying a more recent update to NuGet Packager, such as [this one](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca?SRC=VSIDE) from April 2015, or via the Extensions and Updates GUI in VS2013.

If you check in About Visual Studio, you should see the NuGet Package Manager with a version number that is more recent than the one you would get with a fresh install, even if you ran Update 4 after the install.

Comment: ...and why can't they just warn us "Microsoft NuGet Package upgrade skipped due to newer version already installed." It's not an error if it did it on purpose.

Comment: This was the case for me as well. I was installing VS2015 Enterprise Edition. Maybe one day Microsoft will take care of all the low-hanging fruit.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this problem by installing NuGet 3.0 after downloading it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/nuget/release-notes/nuget-3.0.0) and opening the [CMD prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kBC7.jpg) as administrator.