# Installing Visual Studio 2013: "Microsoft Nuget package failed"

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7

Trying to install Visual Studio Express 2013 for windows desktop:

System specs: Windows 7 64bit pro

After installing I get this message.
[image]

Restarting does not solve the problem and after that VS will not start.

Here is the important part of the log file that I could find:

```
[3168:2C1C][2015-02-07T00:08:57]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: nugetwdexpress2013
[314C:315C][2015-02-07T00:08:57]i301: Applying execute package: nugetwdexpress2013, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{D9706C72-EB6E-37CC-8E21-FCDC0F9F93EE}v2.8.50926.663\packages\WPT\NuGetWDExpress2013.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
[3168:2C1C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (nugetwdexpress2013) failed: Error Message Id: 1722 ErrorMessage: There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  
[314C:315C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[314C:315C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[3168:2C1C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[3168:2C1C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: nugetwdexpress2013 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 3280896  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 208896
[3168:2C1C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80070643 Msi Messages:1722 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[3168:2C1C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147023293 (0x80070643), Error Message=1722, Result Detail=, Vital=False, Package Action=Install, Package Id=nugetwdexpress2013
[3168:2C1C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]w350: Applied non-vital package: nugetwdexpress2013, encountered error: 0x80070643. Continuing...
[314C:315C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]i325: Registering dependency: {b8a9dbc1-1fd4-4103-a83b-a2896f193ea0} on package provider: {D9706C72-EB6E-37CC-8E21-FCDC0F9F93EE}, package: nugetwdexpress2013
[314C:315C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]i325: Registering dependency: {b8a9dbc1-1fd4-4103-a83b-a2896f193ea0} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.Help3,v12, package: help3_vs_msi
[3168:2C1C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: vs_postclean_wdexpress
[314C:315C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]i301: Applying execute package: vs_postclean_wdexpress, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\103DCF929ECE0368D6CB25FD0EBC7930508B1614\packages\VS_Clean\VS_PostClean_wdexpress.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\103DCF929ECE0368D6CB25FD0EBC7930508B1614\packages\VS_Clean\VS_PostClean_wdexpress.exe" /full /install /log C:\Users\0CTODR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_wdexpress_full_20150206233343_042_vs_postclean_wdexpress.log'
[3168:2C1C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vs_postclean_wdexpress MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 0  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[3168:2C1C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[3168:2C1C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[3168:2C1C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[3168:2C1C][2015-02-07T00:09:00]i319: Applied execute package: vs_postclean_wdexpress, result: 0x0, restart: None
```

I have tried re-installing .net frame work and re-installing VS multiple times. 
If someone could tell me what to try next that would be great.

Comment: The trace doesn't contain enough details, just "it didn't work".  Pretty unhealthy of course, usually a strong sign that your machine is too wonky.  You can install [Nuget separately](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca), maybe you get a better diagnostic.

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671562/microsoft-nuget-package-installation-failed-error-while-installing-visual-st

Answer (score 0):

Answer from http://johnlouros.com/blog/how-to-fix-VS2015-CTP6-NuGet-installation-failure seems to be:

- download Visual Studio ISO image,
- extract shipped NuGet cab,
- uninstall current NuGet version (the web-auto-installer pulled a latest-but-broken version),
- install version extracted from ISO

That said, while writing this, I've tried running Control Panel, Visual studio, modify program, Repair and it now starts so that night work for you too!
Hth

Answer (score 0):

So basically I could not figure out what was wrong here and nothing was working. I think this was an issue with an old harddrive that I replaced. Even after I cloned the drive I had to reinstall my OS to fix this as well as some other problems